# How to add text that does NOT belong in any section

Tags: text, report

Lets say that I'm writing a **report** document. So, in a chapter I have lets say a section and what I wish to do, is to add text **AFTER** the section, which belongs to the first chapter and not in any chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}

%%% FOR DUMMY TEXT  %%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \label{1}

    Hello darkness my old friend. %How can I append text here after section 1.1?

        \section{First Section}
        \label{1.1}

        \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: How you imagine that some text written after  `section` doesn't belong to it? Please clarify this with adding a  sketch to your question.

Comment: latex has no way to mark that, and traditional typographic conventions have no way to display that to the reader, how do you want it to appear?

Comment: @Zarko this is how I "imagine" it.

Comment: This text still belong to a section :-). only it is framed. For this exist many ways how to do this, for example use `\frame`, or use boxes  `tcolorbox`, etc. You should correct question title and content.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
no, I do not wish for a box this is just a simple draw at Paint just to tell you what I am trying to do here. Lets say you write an analytical report on a matter. You begin a chapter by its introduction, then you start sectioning it and then you wish to add a conclusion but in order to do so you don't want to add  it either to a previous nor a new section.

Comment: @Broxigar, read David comments. Sorry, this is not possible.

Comment: @Broxigar Theoretically, it is _clearly_ impossible. I have two _workarounds_ for it: (1 -- very bad) indent the section like lists and (2) make a new section named "Conclusion". In the current state your question is very unclear and opinion-based.

Comment: @Broxigar in any traditional publication you would do something like `\section*{Conclusion}` for the final notes, otherwise the reader has no indication that it is not part of the last section

Comment: you can do this by specifying a different font, size, color or you can use a marker. `\section*{Conclusion}` as in @DavidCarlisle is a kind of marker.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I altered the way of my document to have a Conclusion section for every Chapter. Maybe looks better this way idk

Answer (score 1):

The only real indication if a text is still part of a section are the marks in the headline (if the document even displays the headline). So for making some text not part of a section it should be enough to reset the mark in the headline:

```
\documentclass{book}

%%% FOR DUMMY TEXT  %%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \label{1}

    Hello darkness my old friend. %How can I append text here after section 1.1?

        \section{First Section}
        \label{1.1}

        \lipsum\lipsum

        \markright{}
        \lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```